# Find an integer value in Objective-C enum

Tags: objective-c, enums

Is it possible in Objective-C to see if a `int` value is in a particular `enum`? For instance, in this enum:

```
enum  {
  ValidationLoginFailed         = 2000,
  ValidationSessionTokenExpired = 2001,
  ValidationSessionTokenInvalid = 2002,
  ValidationEmailNotFound       = 2003  
}; 
typedef int ValidationStatusCodes;
```

is it possible to see if an arbitrary integer value is in the `ValidationStatusCodes` `enum`?

```
[ValidationStatusCodes contains:intResponseCode]
```

or at least

```
[self intIsInRangeofEnum:ValidationStatusCodes forValue:intResponseCode]
```

Answer (score 9):

There's no simpler way than just doing

```
(ValidationLoginFailed == intResponseCode ||
ValidationSessionTokenExpired == intResponseCode ||
ValidationSessionTokenInvalid == intResponseCode ||
ValidationEmailNotFound == intResponseCode)
```

In general, C is not very helpful for doing dynamic things or reflecting on types, and enums are a C feature.

Answer (score 3):

Not with an `enum`. An `enum` is not an objective-C object, so you can't send it messages as you're doing.

Maybe use an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little dated, but the standard I have seen in software design is to use a bitmask where each of these values is a discrete state with a bit-shift. In some cases, your enum values can be combinations of other values.

```
enum  {
  ValidationLoginFailed         = 0, //0
  ValidationSessionTokenExpired = 1 << 0, //1
  ValidationSessionTokenInvalid = 1 << 1, //2
  ValidationEmailNotFound       = 1 << 2  //4
}; 
typedef int ValidationStatusCodes;
```

For your use-case you would `&` your result with all of the items in the set:

```
int allStates = (ValidationLoginFailed | ValidationSessionTokenExpired | 
   ValidationSessionTokenInvalid | ValidationEmailNotFound); //7

if(val & allStates){
   //some logic here
}
```

Comment: Note that it is essential to this answer is that the enum values are mutually exclusive. This will not work for the values given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as long as this question is up again. There's a nice open source project [JREnum](https://github.com/rentzsch/JREnum)

Which allows to do the following thing:

```
JREnumDeclare( ValidationStatusCodes,
  ValidationLoginFailed         = 2000,
  ValidationSessionTokenExpired = 2001,
  ValidationSessionTokenInvalid = 2002,
  ValidationEmailNotFound       = 2003  
);
```

And then `ValidationStatusCodesByValue()` returns `NSDictionary` which keys are corresponding `NSNumber`s. So:

```
if ([ValidationStatusCodesByValue() objectForKey:@(intResponseCode)])
    ...
```

Answer (score -3):

[UPDATE]

Found this method in some C++ posts which, although not entirely dynamic, does the trick with minimal fuss:

Add range extents to enum entries:

```
enum  {
  ValidationLoginFailed=2000,
  ValidationSessionTokenExpired=2001,
  ValidationSessionTokenInvalid=2002,
  ValidationEmailNotFound=2003
  ValidationSucccesMIN=ValidationLoginFailed,
  ValidationSucccesMAX=ValidationEmailNotFound,
  ValdationValidSuccessCode=9999,
  ValdationInvalidCode=10000

}; 
typedef int ValidationStatusCodes;
```

then something along these lines:

```
-(ValidationStatusCodes)isReponseCodeValid{

for (int i=ValidationSucccesMIN; i<=ValidationSucccesMAX; i++) {
    if(returnCode==i){
        return ValdationValidSuccessCode;
    }
}

return ValdationInvalidCode;
}
```

obviously there are far more than just these 4 codes in the final app and there will a block of corresponding error ones too.

Comment: How does that differ (other than in complexity/performance) from simply checking if "returnCode" is between the min and max values?